# MYSQL Query Not Working, 2 database in one php file

Tags: php, mysql

I have other php files which accesses 2 database, one for the back end of the php site and the other is for the backup, when I update or insert to the back end database, I want that the backup also receives the same of what the back end receives, yet my code seems to not work, can anyone please help me? Newbie here.. Sorry also if wrong grammar.

php clip inside php file containing the php query

```
$d_id = $_POST['computer_id'];
$brand = $_POST['d_brand'];
$model= $_POST['d_model'];
$office = getOfficeId($conn,$_POST['d_office_id']);
$serial_no = $_POST['d_serial_no'];
$type = $_POST['d_type'];
$personnel = $_POST['d_personnel'];
$job_description = $_POST['job_d'];


if(isset($_POST['bundled'])){
    $checkboxOS = $_POST['bundled'];
}

$dbh1 = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database1);
if($dbh1->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database' . $dbh1->connect_error);
}

if (mysqli_query($dbh1,"INSERT INTO computer (Computer_id, Brand, Model, Serial_no, Type, Personnel, Job_description, Status, Office_id, User_id) 
                        VALUES ('$d_id','$brand', '$model', '$serial_no', '$type', '$personnel', '$job_description', 'OK', $office, 1);" )) 
{
    $dbh2 = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database2);
    if($dbh2->connect_errno > 0){   
        die('Unable to connect to database' . $dbh2->connect_error);
    }else {
            if(mysqli_query($dbh2, "INSERT INTO computer (computer_id, Brand, Model, Serial_no, Type, Personnel, Job_description, Status, Office_id, User_id) 
                                     VALUES ('$d_id','$brand', '$model', '$serial_no', '$type', '$personnel', '$job_description', 'OK', $office, 1);")) 
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('New record created successfully');</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                die('Error!' . $dbh2->connect_error);
            }
    }
}else{
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

The first query in $dbh1 works, but the insert in $dbh2 does not work, help needed please, what is wrong with my code :(

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Well, when I check if the data are stored in phpmyadmin, only dbh1 has stored the data, while in dbh2 its blank

Comment: You're not error checking your queries. Have you looked in the error logs?

Comment: Why not just use mysql's built in replication?

Comment: Use prepared statements you are open to injections.

Comment: This sounds like a horrible way to perform backups to me

Comment: Are you positive both tables have the same `CREATE`? One of the many potential problems with "manual mirroring" such as this is that one table was `ALTER`ed, but that change was not mirrored.

Comment: @Jan Sir, can you suggest a better way to backup? Im just newbie, and a suggestion would be of great help.. thanks

Comment: Search google and/or Stackoverflow for "mysql database backup" and you'll find a ton of information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to select the databases separately like this,

```
mysqli_select_db($database1, $dbh1);

mysqli_select_db($database2, $dbh2);
```

Comment: Sir.. thanks.. a friend of mine helped me and this was part of his code, its working now.. thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 1):

You should close previous connection of mysqli before creating new one.

```
mysqli_close($dbh1);
$dbh2 = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database2);
```